# Cross-compiling x86 shared library to ARM architecture

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have been trying to cross compile x86 GNU scientific library to ARM architecture for execution on my Cyclone V FPGA, after getting errors regarding `libgsl.so: File format not recognised`. I have went to the `gsl-2.4` directory, and ran `./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/local/arm-linux` this seems to work, and create makefiles:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
...
...
config.status: creating utils/Makefile
config.status: creating vector/Makefile
config.status: creating wavelet/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

However, when I then run `make` after some time the command halts with the following error:

```
.libs/sasum.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'libgslcblas.la' failed
make[2]: *** [libgslcblas.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gsl-2.4/cblas'
Makefile:961: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gsl-2.4'
Makefile:663: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried using other tool chains like arm-linux-gnueabihf with similar results. Has anyone get any ideas on why these errors may be occuring, or just how I can finally get this GSL library compiled for ARM architectures!

Thanks in advance

https://pastebin.com/S5HSqmT6 : output from make CC:..

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armel-cross/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armel-cross --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armel-cross --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libgcj --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv5t --with-float=soft --disable-werror --enable-multilib --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabi- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-shared' '-fPIC' '-D' 'PIC' '-O2' '-o' '.libs/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0' '-v' '-march=armv5t' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccdsl841.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -shared -X --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -m armelf_linux_eabi -z relro -o .libs/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib .libs/sasum.o .libs/saxpy.o .libs/scasum.o .libs/scnrm2.o .libs/scopy.o .libs/sdot.o .libs/sdsdot.o .libs/sgbmv.o .libs/sgemm.o .libs/sgemv.o .libs/sger.o .libs/snrm2.o .libs/srot.o .libs/srotg.o .libs/srotm.o .libs/srotmg.o .libs/ssbmv.o .libs/sscal.o .libs/sspmv.o .libs/sspr.o .libs/sspr2.o .libs/sswap.o .libs/ssymm.o .libs/ssymv.o .libs/ssyr.o .libs/ssyr2.o .libs/ssyr2k.o .libs/ssyrk.o .libs/stbmv.o .libs/stbsv.o .libs/stpmv.o .libs/stpsv.o .libs/strmm.o .libs/strmv.o .libs/strsm.o .libs/strsv.o .libs/dasum.o .libs/daxpy.o .libs/dcopy.o .libs/ddot.o .libs/dgbmv.o .libs/dgemm.o .libs/dgemv.o .libs/dger.o .libs/dnrm2.o .libs/drot.o .libs/drotg.o .libs/drotm.o .libs/drotmg.o .libs/dsbmv.o .libs/dscal.o .libs/dsdot.o .libs/dspmv.o .libs/dspr.o .libs/dspr2.o .libs/dswap.o .libs/dsymm.o .libs/dsymv.o .libs/dsyr.o .libs/dsyr2.o .libs/dsyr2k.o .libs/dsyrk.o .libs/dtbmv.o .libs/dtbsv.o .libs/dtpmv.o .libs/dtpsv.o .libs/dtrmm.o .libs/dtrmv.o .libs/dtrsm.o .libs/dtrsv.o .libs/dzasum.o .libs/dznrm2.o .libs/caxpy.o .libs/ccopy.o .libs/cdotc_sub.o .libs/cdotu_sub.o .libs/cgbmv.o .libs/cgemm.o .libs/cgemv.o .libs/cgerc.o .libs/cgeru.o .libs/chbmv.o .libs/chemm.o .libs/chemv.o .libs/cher.o .libs/cher2.o .libs/cher2k.o .libs/cherk.o .libs/chpmv.o .libs/chpr.o .libs/chpr2.o .libs/cscal.o .libs/csscal.o .libs/cswap.o .libs/csymm.o .libs/csyr2k.o .libs/csyrk.o .libs/ctbmv.o .libs/ctbsv.o .libs/ctpmv.o .libs/ctpsv.o .libs/ctrmm.o .libs/ctrmv.o .libs/ctrsm.o .libs/ctrsv.o .libs/zaxpy.o .libs/zcopy.o .libs/zdotc_sub.o .libs/zdotu_sub.o .libs/zdscal.o .libs/zgbmv.o .libs/zgemm.o .libs/zgemv.o .libs/zgerc.o .libs/zgeru.o .libs/zhbmv.o .libs/zhemm.o .libs/zhemv.o .libs/zher.o .libs/zher2.o .libs/zher2k.o .libs/zherk.o .libs/zhpmv.o .libs/zhpr.o .libs/zhpr2.o .libs/zscal.o .libs/zswap.o .libs/zsymm.o .libs/zsyr2k.o .libs/zsyrk.o .libs/ztbmv.o .libs/ztbsv.o .libs/ztpmv.o .libs/ztpsv.o .libs/ztrmm.o .libs/ztrmv.o .libs/ztrsm.o .libs/ztrsv.o .libs/icamax.o .libs/idamax.o .libs/isamax.o .libs/izamax.o .libs/xerbla.o -lm -soname libgslcblas.so.0 -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/../lib/crtn.o
.libs/sasum.o: file not recognized: File format not recognised
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and then:

```
.libs/sasum.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Comment: try --target=arm-linux-gnueabi rather than --host.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that worked and the error no longer occurs. However, running `./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/local/arm-linux` still doesn't produce the correct files. The output I get is `libgslcblas.so.0.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=60aa5806266933c1796fd6a55a0bd817f7e885f0, not stripped` @mevets

Comment: Your original set of configure switches was correct.  `--target` is only for when you are _building a cross-compiler_, not for when you are trying to cross-compile.  The problem looks to me like you haven't got the matching cross-linker for your cross-compiler, or else the compiler driver isn't successfully finding it.

Comment: Hi @zwol, I'm unfamiliar with this really. So I need to download a cross-linker? I have a makefile where I link the libraries, but when I run this I get error `ligsl.so: File not recognised file format not recognised`. This was the original error that made me start searching for cross-compiling. I could post my makefile, if that would be of any significance?

Comment: @JoelM What would actually be more useful is if you posted the output of `ls -l $(dirname $(which arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc))`.

Comment: I think @JoelM is right. It looks like the tool path is not quite correct, or it looks like `--sysroot` is not quite correct. Usually you want a `--sysroot=...` in you `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` so the correct headers nd libs are used during the cross-compile. But beware, I have also seen Autotools fail to honor `--sysroot`. Sometimes you need to patch an Autotools project to use it.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means @zwol, but when I run `ls -l` in the directory where `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` is held I get `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          23 Feb 11  2016 arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -> arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-5`. @jww, I'm not really familiar with sysroot, and as you can tell from the commands I've been running I haven't included any `--sysroot=...` in the flags section. How would I find out what this should be set to? Aplogies in advance if I sound stupid!

Comment: @JoelM In English, I am asking you for a _complete_ `ls -l` listing of the directory containing `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`.  I would also like to know if that directory is on your PATH, or if you set CC to point to the cross-compiler, or what.

Comment: @jww `--sysroot` again should only be necessary when _building_ the cross-toolchain, not when using it.

Comment: @JoelM To answer the earlier query, yes, you do need a cross-linker (and a cross-assembler) to go with the cross-compiler. Since you said you downloaded the cross-compiler rather than building it yourself, I suspect you do already have them and they're just not being located correctly.

Comment: Hi @zwol, that's what I thought, but it's in my /usr/bin/ directory which is pretty lengthy. Shall I add it as a seperate comment? I am unsure whether it is on my PATH. Typically when I compiled I would use a makefile I got from Intel, however I have added a new library and functions to my program and now it won't compile due to the platform incompatibilites. This is the first time I have ever had to even consider studying libraries, linking, cross-compiling etc. Yes you are correct - I downloaded the cross-compiler.

Comment: If it's `/usr/bin` then it's definitely on your PATH, or else something much worse is wrong.  In that case what I want to see is the output of this shell command (type _exactly as shown_): `cd /usr/bin && ls -l arm-linux-*`

Comment: OK, so, you _do_ have a cross-linker (`arm-linux-gnueabi-ld`).  There are two possibilities at this point: either the cross-linker isn't getting found correctly, or your object files are somehow not ARM object files.  The next thing I need you to try is: run make until it fails; then run it again as `make CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v"` and post the _complete and unedited_ output of that command on a pastebin somewhere and edit the link into the question.  It will be very long -- don't try to post it here directly -- but I really need to see _all_ of it.

Comment: @zwol - I have to disagree with you with respect to `--sysroot`. It is intended to change the logical root for headers and libraries. It is not limited to building toolchains. I use it in all my cross-compiled projects.

Comment: @JoelM Aw heck, that has everything _but_ the bit I needed, because libtool ate the `-v` at the exact point where I wanted it to apply.  Please open a shell window and enter the directory `/home/jmholland/gsl-2.4/cblas`.  Then, go to line 2800 of that pastebin (the one that starts "`libtool: link: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC`"). Copy and paste that entire line except for the leading "libtool: link:" into the shell window, and append a `-v` option, and run it.  Edit the output into the question.  The output of `file .libs/sasum.o` would also be helpful.

Comment: @JoelM We're finally starting to get somewhere. The build process _is_ running the ARM cross-linker.  The problem is that `sasum.o` is an _x86_ object file, that is, it wasn't cross-compiled!  Now we need to figure out why _that_ happened.  New thing for you to try: `make clean > /dev/null 2>&1; make > build.log 2>&1; if [ $? -ne 0 ] then grep sasum build.log; fi` and post the output.

Comment: @zwol, I ran the above command and there was no output. I decided to reconfigure, and I don't know how, but I now have the 32-bit ARM libraries I need `libgslcblas.so.0.0.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=4d24718381bb567a3a728f6377ab184ffbcee375, not stripped` and `libgsl.so.23.0.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=933f4ee8ebf45c9800ed3575fa7a1c3e294e4609, not stripped`. Maybe it was the makefiles? Either way, you helped me get to this stage. How do I credit you?

Comment: Hi @zwol, is there any reason why linking a shared library may cause a program to exit immediately? After following your advice and trying to execute my program by calling `./host` it exits immediately and returns to the command line. It works fine when I put the static libraries onto my platform, but I am still interested in knowing why this may occur?

Comment: @JoelM Yes, that is some kind of crash inside initial processing of shared libraries, which could happen for several different reasons.  Please ask a new question about that.  Include in the question the the complete and unedited output of `LD_DEBUG=all ./host`.